# Java RTSP get contents

Tags: java, download, inputstream, rtsp

Can I download the contents from an RTSP url in java? Just like we can get contents of an HTTP url as an InputStream...

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses "protocol handlers" to determine how to retrieve the resource identified by a URL.  It's not limited just to the HTTP/HTTPS.

Apparently the Java Media Framework API can access RTSP resources.  I don't know if it installs a protocol handler for RTSP or if it uses some different strategy.  Google for Java Media Framework RTSP for all the details.